# How can notice an error with parameters, throwable and message

Tags: java, newrelic

I see the api for noticeError, and I have the options

```
NewRelic.noticeError(Throwable throwable)
NewRelic.noticeError(Throwable throwable, Map<String, String> params)
NewRelic.noticeError(String message, Map<String, String> params)
```

I need (ok, want) an option like

```
NewRelic.noticeError(String message, Throwable throwable, Map<String, String> params)
```

Is there a reason it isn't present? I can not find a valid alternative:

If I wrap the original exception in a new one with my custom message, I can't see the original exception in the Error panel

If I pass the custom message as a param value in the map, I can't see that message in the Error panel

Is there anything I can see? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what calling it twice with the same Throwable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NewRelic.noticeError calls are per transaction, it is perfectly acceptable to run one after another.

Instead of wrapping, try running them like this:

```
NewRelic.noticeError(Throwable throwable, Map<String, String> params)
NewRelic.noticeError(String message, Map<String, String> params)
```

Comment: It is somehow odd. If I call noticeError with an exception first, and then the string message, all the exception information is loss in the error page. But if I call noticeError with a message first, and the exception second, everything shows in the screen. Anyway, is a valid answer